# How do I access members in John Resig's class in ajax callbacks?

Tags: javascript

I am using John resig's implementation class mentioned here: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Now I have a function, which is actually a callback supplied to an ajax method. Now, how do I access the class members inside this function?

**---EDIT---**

**CASE I**

Suppose, here is the class I defined:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});
```

And I use it like:

```
var p = new Person(true);

$.ajax({url: url, success: p.dance});
```

Then, in the dance method, this.dancing wont work, because this wont point to the object p.

**CASE II:**

I am using knockoutjs (http://knockoutjs.com) for binding my UI to the objects. Suppose we have:

```
var AppViewModel = Class.extend({
  person: new Person()
});
```

and binding in html would be:

```
<button data-bind="click: person.dance">Dance</button>
```

in this case, the 'this' in dance would point to the object of AppViewModel, and not person.

The latter case is more important for me.

Comment: You'll need to provide some code so we get the picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is my 'this'? Using objects method as a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085674/where-is-my-this-using-objects-method-as-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var p = new Person(true);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: p.dance.bind(p)
});
```

`bind()` is available in latest browsers but you can provide a graceful downgrade for older browsers as [shown on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

And in your preferred case of KnockoutJS you could write this:

```
<button data-bind="click: person.dance.bind(person)">Dance</button>
```

I'm not a KnockoutJS user but as I've seen a very similar example on their documentation pages this should likely work.